# Using Boost Serialize With A Qt Plugin

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, boost

All, I am attempting to serialize a Qt Plugin infrastructure using boost.  A quick description of my plugin infrastructure -- All plugins are factories, let's call them ObjectFactories.  Each plugin .so/.dll is constructed from two classes

My problem is that when I serialize an object from my plugin (in a console test program), I get an exception of `derived class not registered or exported`

objectfactory.cpp/.h:

```
class ObjectFactory : public QObject, public [PluginInterface]
{
    //most important method
    BaseObject * createBaseObject();
}
```

derivedobject.h:

```
#include "base_object.h"

#include <boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/basic_text_oarchive.hpp>

namespace MyNamespace
{

class DerivedObject : public BaseObject
{
public:
    DerivedObject();

    ~DerivedObject();

private:
    BaseObjectData<double> m_data;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<BaseObject>(*this);
        ar & m_data.data(); // T & BaseObjectData::data() - returns reference
    }
};

}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(MyNamespace::DerivedObject) //Register our class for serialization/deserialization
```

At the bottom of the derivedobject.cpp:

```
 BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(Mynamespace::DerivedObject)
```

However, I am still getting

```
what(): unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported
```

If anyone could offer any advice it would be appreciated.  I would be glad to add any more sources that I need.  **An important note**, the two classes (`ObjectFactory` and `DerivedObject`) exist within the same *.so   I don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got it...

In my base and derived headers:

```
#include <boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/basic_text_oarchive.hpp>
```

while in my test program:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
```

I had to make those two match up.